# plot the cumulative distribution of a secondary data nested within the one frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

When we consider the following example:

```
set.seed(123)

begin1 <- sample(1980:2000, 500, replace = T)
typ1 <- sample(letters[1:2], 500, replace = T)
begin2 <- sample(1980:2000, 500, replace = T)
typ2 <- sample(letters[1:1], 500, replace = T)

df1 <- data.frame(begin1, typ1, begin2, typ2)
```

We can plot a simple cumulative density plot of `begin1` in respect to `typ1` with the following command

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(begin1, colour = typ1)) + stat_ecdf()
```

How can I plot the distribution of `begin2` on the same axis??
Ie. I want the cumulative distribution in a new colour and it included in the legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can i) reformat your `data.frame`, ii) use another `aes`, eg:

```
id <- rep(c("A", "B"), each=500)
df <- data.frame(begin=c(begin1, begin2), typ=c(typ1, typ2), id=id)
ggplot(df, aes(begin, colour = typ, linetype=id)) + stat_ecdf()
```

is this what you want?